# image fetching is not working in OSClass when i gives twice

Tags: osclass

I'm using **OSClass**. I'm new for this.

In `...\oc-content\themes\modern\item.php`, i'm using following codes,

```
<div class="image slider">
    <?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
        <?php if( osc_count_item_resources() > 0 ) { ?>
            <?php for ( $i = 0; osc_has_item_resources(); $i++ ) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" width="100%" height="240px;" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />

            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>  
</div>


<div class="layout slider">
    <?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
        <?php if( osc_count_item_resources() > 0 ) { ?>
            <?php for ( $i = 0; osc_has_item_resources(); $i++ ) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" width="100%" height="240px;" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />

            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>  
</div>
```

Here, `image slider` gives images. But, `layout slider` gives empty `div`. I'm using same code for both `div`.

Where is Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `<?php osc_reset_resources(); ?>` after `<div class="layout slider">` and before the second `for`, the iterator of the resources has to be reset.

Comment: You could post them on the official forums : http://forums.osclass.org/ I think you could get more help there, I visit them daily

Comment: I have the similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456326/show-images-with-php-and-bootstrap-carousel but before this I have one more part of code you can see the code in the answer of question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432061/bootstrap-carousel-with-php ... Why we cant use twice code for fetching images ?