# Bootstrap carousel with OS-Class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, osclass

I need to create dynamically bootstrap carousel like this:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    etc...
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="someIMG.jpg" alt="...">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="someIMG-nn.jpg" alt="...">

    </div>
    etc...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Now I have a osclass functions which I call to create dynamically bootstrap carousel:

```
**<?php osc_run_hook('item_detail', osc_item() ) ; ?>
                    <?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() && (osc_count_item_resources() > 0) ) { ?>**

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
**<?php $i=0;?>**
                            **<?php while( osc_has_item_resources() ) { ?>**
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="**<?php echo $i; $i+1;?>**" class="active"></li>
    **<?php } ?>** 
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
**<?php while( osc_has_item_resources() ) { ?>**
    <div class="item">
      <img src="**<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>**" alt="...">


    </div>
    **<?php } ?>** 


  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>


</div>
```

I'm beginner so I don't know what can be a problem here. In my logic I think that I write good but what I write don't work... Two while is the problem or something else?

please help, sorry for my English. THANKS!

Comment: simply I was tried to include function to dinamicly create HTML with twitter bootstrap carousel but dont work well...

Comment: If someone comes here for an answer, ```osc_has_item_resources()```  cannot be used twice without resetting the query. Try ```osc_reset_items()``` after first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. But you're using that loop twice and that may not work. I'm not sure what `osc_has_item_resources()` does with the records. But try this.

Set a variable equal to whatever is in `osc_count_item_resources()` and then loop that many times to build the carousel indicators. After you do that, use `while( osc_has_item_resources() )` to loop through and build the items.

```
<?php osc_run_hook('item_detail', osc_item() ) ; ?>
<?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() && (osc_count_item_resources() > 0) ) { ?>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php $itemCount = osc_count_item_resources(); ?>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) { ?>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="active"></li>
<?php } ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while( osc_has_item_resources() ) { ?>
    <div class="item<?php echo ($i === 0) ? ' active': ''; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" alt="...">
    </div>
<?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thats ok, thanks, but when I write the same code just html work fine, but this created dinamicly then dont work well... the code is the same in two cases...

Comment: Here is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/gy6we7xt/ but I dont know why is this hidden ?

Comment: Now I know what is the problem. The first class=item must be class="item active" ... HOW I CAN DO THAT ?

Comment: I updated the code. I put in a check if it's the first one in the loop to echo active. `<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="active<?php echo ($i === 0) ? 'active': ''; ?>"></li>`. There was also a spot in that LI tag that was incrementing `$i` from your code before that was not needed. I removed that.

Comment: now, all have the class active ... so dont work again

Comment: here I must add active on first item: <div class="active item" style="">

Comment: Ok, I updated it to have it put the active on the div.

Comment: please help me: I need one mre time to add osc_resources_url() and cunting... and I add to the end of this code: <?php for($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) { ?>
            
        
<div class="row hidden-xs" id="mediaCarouselThumbs" style="padding: 15px;">
  <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
              <a href="#" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;$i+1;?>" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>);">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?> but DONT WORK!

Answer (score 0):

for botstrap4 works with replace

```
<div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($i === 0) ? ' active': ''; ?>">
  <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" alt="...">
</div>
```