# Show images with php and bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create an list of images with twitter bootstrap so I write:

```
<?php osc_run_hook('item_detail', osc_item() ) ; ?>
<?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() && (osc_count_item_resources() > 0) ) { ?>
<div class="row hidden-xs" id="mediaCarouselThumbs" style="padding: 15px;">
    <?php $itemCount = osc_count_item_resources(); ?>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) { ?>
                                                    <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
                                <a href="#" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;$i+1;?>" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>);">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div><?php } ?>
                            <!---->

                                            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

All is fine but echo osc_resource_url(); dont give me the right url and dont change it in the loop, also with $i is everything fine and work well... So after raun this code I get:

```
<div class="row hidden-xs" id="mediaCarouselThumbs" style="padding: 15px;">
                                                        <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
                                <a href="#" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://dive.agroagro.com/0.);">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div>                                                    <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
                                <a href="#" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://dive.agroagro.com/0.);">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div>                                                    <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
                                <a href="#" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://dive.agroagro.com/0.);">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div>                            <!---->

                                            </div>
```

What I need to do to change image URL on every loop. Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `osc_resource_url()` (in your current code) is "static" and is not affected by the current loop. This is the reason why all images are the same. One solution is to pass an argument to this function.

Because I have no idea what is the main job that this function do (are there any arguments that can be passed, what value will be returned, etc.), I'll suggest simple solution using array for images and urls:

```
<?php
    $itemCount = osc_count_item_resources();
    $images = array(
        array('url' => '#', 'image' => 'http://dive.agroagro.com/0.jpg'),
        array('url' => '#', 'image' => 'http://dive.agroagro.com/1.jpg'),
        array('url' => '#', 'image' => 'http://dive.agroagro.com/2.jpg'),
        array('url' => '#', 'image' => 'http://dive.agroagro.com/3.jpg')
    );
?>

    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) { ?>
        <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
            <a href="<?php echo $images[$i]['url']; ?>" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $images[$i]['image']; ?>);">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: no no no, I also images must et from database ... images are not the same everytime

Comment: I also try this: <div class="row hidden-xs" id="mediaCarouselThumbs" style="padding: 15px;">
    <?php for ( $i = 0; osc_has_item_resources(); $i++ ) { ?>
                            <div class="pull-left" style="width: 11.11%;">
                                <a href="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" data-target="#mediaCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>);">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div><?php } ?>
                            <!---->

</div>

Comment: I'm guessing but `osc_resource_url()` gets the images from database based on some arguments (conditions), right? In your loop you **must** send something to that function, if you want to get the right content. It's no matter if you send arguments to or use global variables, but all variables that would be send must be inside the loop.

In the above example I use an array because this is the easiest way when using `for(...){...}` loop. Maybe I can help you more, if you provide the entire code of `osc_resource_url()`. :)

Comment: The full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/33/ , so as you can see, the first part of code work well, but second that I post in question not work ... Why?

Comment: Before the second loop add this code: `<?php View::newInstance()->_erase('resources'); ?>`. I found this [here](http://forums.osclass.org/development/thumbnail-is-not-showing/msg3254/#msg3254).